# print all the lines according to the maching string

Tags: python-2.6, python-2.x

I have a file name new which contain the following data:

```
1111
2012-5-12
new
p0
2222
2012-10-12
old
p1
3333
2012-15-12
new
p0
4444
2012-5-11
new
p1
5555
2011-5-12
old
p0
```

In this file each id has following data like id, date,status and value(1111,2012-5-12,new,p0)....
In this file i have to print the data of all the ids which have status value "new"..
And my output should be like this:

```
1111
2012-5-12
new
p0
3333
2012-15-12
new
p0
4444
2012-5-11
new
p1
```

i tried with the following code :

```
f1 = open('new','r')
output = open('new1','w')
lines = f1.readlines()
n =0
for i, line in enumerate(lines):       
    if n > 3:
        output.close()
        file1=open('new1','r')
        file2=open('new2','w')
        lines= file1.readlines()
        status = lines[2].strip()
        if status == 'new':
         for line in lines:
                file2.write(line)

        output = open('new1','w')       
        output.write(line)
        n = 1

    else:
        output.write(line)
        n = n + 1
```

new2 and new1 have following output: 
(new2)=======

```
p0
2012-5-11
new
p1
0
```

(new1)===========

```
p1
2011-5-12
old
p0
```

program will take the first 4 line and write it new1..
Accordingly it will search for status == "new" if found then write all the four lines to new2 other wise again read the next four line upto the length  of the file..

problem: I am not geeting the right data in new2 it should contain the data like this:

```
1111
2012-5-12
new
p0
3333
2012-15-12
new
p0
4444
2012-5-11
new
p1
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: f1 = open('new','r')
output = open('new1','w')
lines = f1.readlines()
n =0
for i, line in enumerate(lines):       
    if n > 3:
        output.close()
        file1=open('new1','r')
        file2=open('new2','w')
        lines= file1.readlines()
        status = lines[2].strip()
        if status == 'new':
         for line in lines:
                file2.write(line)
       
        output = open('new1','w')       
        output.write(line)
        n = 1
           
    else:
        output.write(line)
        n = n + 1

Comment: But i dont want to take data in new1 and again write to new2...i should take the data from new and put it in another file according to my above mentioned output, thats it

Comment: Please edit your question to put in that code properly formatted. Also explain what exactly is failing or how the result differs from the expected.

Comment: I am done with the editing in the main question please see the question again and reply back to me... Thanks

Comment: Your question is clear now - though I don't have time for an elaborated answer at the moment try the following: Create a class representing your items. Read the source file and create an object of that class for each item. Then filter that list by writing only the items with status new to a new file.

Comment: i tried with all my efforts, if you can help me then it will be very usefull for me... Dont elaborate just correct my code and reply back on it.. i will understand the flow by myself...Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('new', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = [lines[4 * i:4 * i + 4] for i in range(len(lines) / 4)]
new_data = [d for d in data if d[2] == 'new']

with open('new1', 'w') as f:
    for d in new_data:
        f.write('\n'.join(d))
```